# Kendo UI Grid error - save is not defined

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have following `Kendo UI` grid. I am trying to alert the updated values from the grid. But I am getting following error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: save is not defined

How can we resolve this error and show all the updated values from the grid?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/Z86dq/24/)

[image]

**Body**

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<br />
<input type="button" value="Save Row" onclick="save();" />
<input type="button" value="Submit To Server" onclick="" />

<script id="gridItems" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <tr data-uid="#= uid #">
        <td title="#= EmpName #">
            #= EmpName #
        </td>
        <td title="#= Department #">
            #= Department #
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

**Javascript**

```
var records = [
    {
        "foo": 1,
         "EmpName":"A1",
         "Department": "D1"
    },
    {
        "foo": 2,
        "EmpName":"A2",
        "Department": "D2"
    }
              ];

var myDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: records,
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "foo",
            fields: {
                    foo: {type: "number"},
                    EmpName: {type: "string"},
                    Department: {type: "string"}
                    }
                }            
            }
});

var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: myDataSource,
    columns: ["EmpName", "Department"],
    editable: "inline",
    selectable: "row",
    rowTemplate: kendo.template($("#gridItems").html()),

    dataBound: function() 
    {
        //Click on each row
        $("#grid tbody tr").on("click", function(e) 
        {          
            if (!$(this).hasClass('k-grid-edit-row')) 
            {
                //Make the row editable
                $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").editRow($(this));
            }
        });
    }
}).data("kendoGrid");

function save() 
{
    var row = $("#grid tbody").find(".k-grid-edit-row"); 
    if(row.length == 1) 
    {
        $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").saveRow(row);
    }

    var updatedData = grid.dataSource.data();
    alert(updatedData.length);

    for (var i = 0; i < updatedData.length; i++) 
    {
       var dataitem = updatedData[i].EmpName;
       alert(dataitem);
    }


}
```

**REFERENCES**

1. [Grid / Batch editing](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/editing.html)
2. [Kendoui Grid Editing Tips and tricks](http://onabai.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/kendoui-grid-editing-records-when-using-rowtemplate-tips-and-tricks/)
3. [Row-Template](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/rowtemplate.html)
4. [Pop-up Data Editing](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/editing-popup.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the click function like this rather than used inline

```
<input type="button" id="saveVal" value="Save Row"  />

$('#saveVal').click(function (){
     save();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z86dq/25/)

**OR**

put your script after your dom is ready,

[**DEMO2**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z86dq/26/)

[image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate which is the line that you updated in second fiddle?

Comment: I have not updated any code but change the option(from onLoad to No wrap- in<body>) as shown into image at above. The option you can get at left sidebar of jsFiddle.